# Create Term Document Matrix of Bi Grams?

Tags: r, matrix, nlp, text-mining, term-document-matrix

I am doing text mining on large data set. I was able to create TDM and DTM and was able to perform my analysis using TDF & IDF. But can we create a Term Document Matrix or Document Term Matrix for Bi Grams in R? I know similar facility is available in Mahout but I am looking for a way to do this in R?

Answer (score 1):

Following Code Worked for me:

```
BigramTokenizer <- function(x) {RWeka::NGramTokenizer(x, RWeka::Weka_control(min = 2, max = 2))}
myTdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus, control = list(tokenize = BigramTokenizer))
```